# I need advice on this 'else' block

Tags: python

Why does the else statement get printed here?

```
for elem in data:
    if choose_id == elem['id']:
        print(f"{elem['ip']} : {elem['id']}")
else:
    print("No ID found")
```

output is:

```
ID to search > 6
10.xx.xxx.xx : 6
10.xx.xxx.xx : 6
10.xx.xxx.xx : 6
10.xx.xxx.xx : 6
No ID found
```

I've tried putting in a 'break' statement in the if block but it only iterates once.

I'd appreciate some advice.

Comment: Else gets printed because it's not indented - it's for/else, not if/else.

Comment: In `for ... else` statement `else` part runs if the loop ends without `break`, so that's exactly what happens here.

Comment: @h4z3 I initally had it indented but it just prints 'no id found' for every element

Comment: @bereal where should the `break` go?

Comment: @Posteingang in your case `break` won't help, because you want to iterate to the end. I think, you'll need a variable `found = False` which is set to `True` once you have a match, and in the end print the message if there's no match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case the `for..else` statement won't help, because you want to iterate through the entire list in any case, and the `else` part will run after than. I think, the simplest way is to have a `found` variable, like this:

```
found = False
for elem in data:
    if choose_id == elem['id']:
        found = True
        print(f"{elem['ip']} : {elem['id']}")

if not found:
    print("No ID found")
```

Comment: how do you know they want to iterate to the end of the list? maybe they can break after one `if` clause is met sucesfully

Comment: @Chris_Rands I understood that from the statement _I've tried putting in a 'break' statement in the if block but it only iterates once._, and the fact that the id seems to be non-unique in their output.

Comment: This worked. I never would have thought to use `found = True/False`. Glad this got re-opened, many thanks.